# Out of Memory with Node.js and Redis - Video game

Tags: node.js, out-of-memory, game-engine

We just installed Redis yesterday, because we are thinking about save our entire map, all positions in Redis, as a cache to make the game faster.

We did some tests and trying to save by 70000*70000 we ran out of mmory from node.js.
Because node doesn't accept a process more than 1Go RAM by default using x64 machine.

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/FAQ (last chapter)

We tried again with a smaller one, 7500*7500 and it was okay.
We don't have a such big world map yet, but I'm thinking about the future.

I think that save the map in Redis is really important to have better performance (because we want to check the player movments from server too), but maybe is there a better way?

We could simply run the server using

```
node --max-old-space-size=16000 app.js
```

To allow node to use more, because a video game obviously need more memory than a web application, but I would like to discuss more about that before make choices.

Answer (score 0):

Redis is better choice, we do not recommend to store too much data in node.js heap.